# Cómo hacer que el usuario ingrese varios inputs y yo ordenarlos en un array en el archivo.js

Tags: javascript

Estoy en un curso de JavaScript y no me queda claro como hacer un ejercicio...

La idea es tener un array de varios valores (por ejemplo saldos), luego ordenarlos de menor a mayor (esto lo tendria que hacer con el metodo .sort de los arrays) para luego sacar la mediana (osea el numero que se encuetra justo en la mitad de la lista.
Mi problema está en llevar la informacion del archivo.html al archivo.js.

Yo siempre uso inputs, por ejemplo:

```
<input id="inputNumber">
```

y luego en el archivo.js los recibía con:

```
 const inputNumber = docuement.getElementById("inputNumber")
```

Luego uso su value (inputNumber.value) y asi... el problema es que acá necesitaría VARIOS inputs. Y que se ordenen luego en un array para poder aplicarles el metodo .sort (sé que éste metodo ya te ordena en un array, pero cómo aplico el metodo .sort en todos ellos a la vez para que me los ordene?   y cómo tendría que ingresar el ususario los datos? tengo que poner si o si varios input? no hay alguna opcion en la que el usuario decide cuantos inputs van? y si van todos los datos en el mismo input, cómo los tendria que ingresar el usuario? separando por espacios? por comas? deberia indicarle de que manera ingresarlos?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y hay varias opciones para resolver el problema.

Comment: entiendo.. es que realmente no conozco ninguna opcion... no sabia que existian varias

Answer (score 1):

La forma más fácil es poner todos los `inputs` que necesitas en el maquetado HTML. A estos `inputs` puedes asignarles el nombre de una clase. Por ejemplo:

```
<input id="inputNumber" class="inputUser">
<input id="inputNumber2" class="inputUser">
<input id="inputNumber3" class="inputUser">
```

Con esto puedes obtener todos los elementos que tengan esa clase con javascript:

```
let arrInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputUser");
```

De esta forma `arrInputs` tendrá todos los elementos `input` que tengas en HTML. De ahí solo te quedaría recorrer `arrInputs` y realizar cualquier lógica sobre cada elemento (`input`) como obtener su valor, validarlo, etc.

Esta solo es una forma de hacerlo, en realidad hay muchas.